# Read Integer array from JSON using Jackson for class B from class A

Tags: json, jackson

I have the following class structure:

```
class A {
    int element1;
    B b; 
}

class B {
    Integer[] element2;
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "element1" : 111,
    "b" : {
        "element2":[
            {4457551},{4457552}
        ]
     }
}
```

In yet another class, I am reading the JSONReading value as :

```
private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();


protected <T> T loadConfig("pathOfJson.json", A.class) throws IOException {
    try(InputStream inputStream1 =
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);) {
        return OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(inputStream1, type);
    }
}
```

But, when I run the code, I get the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of int out of START_OBJECT token
```

Am I using the correct format for parsing the JSON? Or is it required that I tell how to parse B class as well? If yes, how can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

So, a simple change in JSON file format worked!

```
{  
    "element1":111"
    "b":{  
        "element2":[  
            4457551,
            4457552
        ]
    }
}
```